# SSRS: hide page footer on exporting to excel

Tags: sql, reporting-services

We are using SQL Server Reporting Server 2014. On exporting report into excel we are getting error "Length cannot be 0. Missing parameter Length". After research, we found that excel doesn't allow more than 255 characters in footer. We would like to hide footer on excel import only.

Is there a global settings on report level which we can apply to hide page footer in excel import. From google search, it is clear that we can add global logic to each text box within page footer to hide it. However, we didn't find any global report level logic to hide page footer in excel import. Can someone help us and provide logic to hide page footer on report level?

Thanks.

```
=(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive = "EXCEL")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use =Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL".

The .IsInteractive you used returns a boolean and tells whether the report is being run interactive.  The .Name returns the format name.

Comment: Do I need to add your suggestion (logic) to each text box in Page footer.

Comment: I fixed it with below logic on each text box in Page Footer.=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL" OR Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML",TRUE,FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

I placed all my textboxes inside a rectangle and turn on/off the visibility based on the answer above. This is so you don't have to do it on each textbox.